# Line feature with elevation points?

Tags: line, google-earth, elevation, global-mapper

I need done seems to be a simple task, but I cannot find out how.

I want to create grid lines for a specific area at a specific angle (which is the easy part).

Now I want on every gridline to be shown the lowest elevation and highest, and by multitude of x every point on the line where the elevation reached the higher mark.

I'm a newbie and self taught using google earth and global mapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily in Global Mapper with the following steps:

1. Select the digitizer tool [image]
2. Right click and select the GRID  option
   [image]
3. In the grid window configure the grid size and location. Make sure to select "Create grid line features"
   [image]
4. Then right click on the selected lines of your  recently created grid and select "Analysis/Measurements" -> "Calculate Elevation/Slope for selected  features"
   [image]
5. The a question box will pop-up asking whether to add point features at the max/min elevations. Select "YES"
   [image]
6. You will have exactly what you want, a grid of lines with markers in the maximum and minimum elevations along each line:
   [image]

You can the customize the lines and markers to look as "x" or anything you want.